# How can I wrap std::wstring in boost::asio::buffer?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost-asio

I am writing a client server application using boost::asio. I want to transfer a structure from a client to the server. The struct has a few std::wstrings in it. How do I encode the structure in boost::asio::buffer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically I use `boost::asio::streambuf` for serializing structures.

**Message.h**

```
#ifndef MESSAGE_H
#define MESSAGE_H

#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>

#include <string>

struct Message
{
    std::string _a;
    std::string _b;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(
            Archive& ar,
            unsigned int version
            )
    {
        ar & _a;
        ar & _b;
    }
};

#endif
```

**client.cpp**

```
#include "Message.h"

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int
main()
{
    Message msg;
    msg._a = "hello";
    msg._b = "world";

    boost::asio::streambuf buf;
    std::ostream os( &buf );
    boost::archive::text_oarchive ar( os );
    ar & msg;

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket( io_service );
    const short port = 1234;
    socket.connect(
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(
                boost::asio::ip::address::from_string( "127.0.0.1" ),
                port
                )
            );

    const size_t header = buf.size();
    std::cout << "buffer size " << header << " bytes" << std::endl;

    // send header and buffer using scatter
    std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> buffers;
    buffers.push_back( boost::asio::buffer(&header, sizeof(header)) );
    buffers.push_back( buf.data() );
    const size_t rc = boost::asio::write(
            socket,
            buffers
            );
    std::cout << "wrote " << rc << " bytes" << std::endl;;
}
```

**server.cpp**

```
#include "Message.h"

#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int
main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    const uint16_t port = 1234;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(
            io_service,
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(
                boost::asio::ip::address::from_string( "127.0.0.1" ),
                port
                )
            );

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket( io_service );
    acceptor.accept( socket );
    std::cout << "connection from " << socket.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;

    // read header
    size_t header;
    boost::asio::read(
            socket,
            boost::asio::buffer( &header, sizeof(header) )
            );
    std::cout << "body is " << header << " bytes" << std::endl;

    // read body
    boost::asio::streambuf buf;
    const size_t rc = boost::asio::read(
            socket,
            buf.prepare( header )
            );
    buf.commit( header );
    std::cout << "read " << rc << " bytes" << std::endl;

    // deserialize
    std::istream is( &buf );
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ar( is );
    Message msg;
    ar & msg;

    std::cout << msg._a << std::endl;
    std::cout << msg._b << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I think this will work fine with sending the data. Does this also work with reading the data from socket? Here we dont know beforehand the size of the incoming strings.

Comment: yes, you'll need to send a fixed length header indicating the size of the buffer.

Comment: It would be helpful if you also update the code for reading the stream using the header info

Comment: I've added a server example showing how to receive the header and body

Comment: At the end of the server example, are there two variables defined with same name `msg`? Does this code compile?

Comment: @Deqing there is a single variable named msg, the code should compile though it has been several years since I wrote it.

Comment: I see. `ar & msg` is using operator &, not defining a reference.