# boost::asio::async_read and boost::asio::streambuf

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, streambuf

I am using async_read with streambuf. However, I would like to limit the amount of data read to 4, so I can properly handle header before going to body.

How can I do that using async_read?

Answer (score 5):

Use two `async_read` operations where the first reads a 4 byte header, and the second reads the message body. Your handler to the first `async_read` should start the `async_read` for the message body.

The asio examples use this technique in a couple of places, the [serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/serialization/connection.hpp) example is one. I also answered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599638/how-can-i-wrap-stdwstring-in-boostasiobuffer/3600460#3600460), though it uses synchronous reads, but the concept is the same.

Comment: +1 for using the richness of the API better than my suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You can guarantee the header is available using [transfer_at_least](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/transfer_at_least.html) as [CompletionCondition on async_read](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read.html).

Any superfluous body data (or further headers) can be processed once you handle the initial header.

Answer (score 0):

```
boost::asio::transfer_exactly(streambuf.size())
```

is what you need.just try using like this:

```
boost::asio::async_read(socket_, 
                        buf,boost::asio::transfer_exactly(size_),
                        boost::bind(callback,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```