# sending a serialized type over a boost-asio socket connection using boost serialization

Tags: c++, sockets, serialization, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to send 1kb of data from a "server" to a "client", but I just can't get it right.
There are a few things that I NEED to do in this:
1) Need to use boost-asio sockets to transfer the data
2) Need to serialize a type I created (Packet) that will contain the data as a string or char*

Here is what is going on:

First, I get 1kb of data from a sample text file on the server. I get this and put it into the Packet type that I created.  I have defined the data field in Packet to hold this data as a std::string. (I tried char* but it didnt work well - see next paragraph).

Second I serialize it using boost text_oarchive . I have no problems serializing the Packet type if it just contains a string, but what I really want is a way to serialize it with the data type being a char array (so that it works better with the socket below)

Third, I send it over a boost asio socket.  Here I have a problem because I can't find a way to send a std::string over the socket connection.  Everything I see as examples and in the documentation need a buffer using some type of char* and not a string.

its just a headache. can you help?

Comment: impossible to answer without code, please edit your question to include the code you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

> Everything I see as examples and in the documentation need a buffer
>   using some type of char* and not a string

That is correct, though it's quite simple to do using Boost.Serialization and Boost.Asio. You can serialize using a `text_oarchive` to a `boost::asio::streambuf` then send the resulting stream buffer contents using a socket.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3599638/283302) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599638/how-can-i-wrap-stdwstring-in-boostasiobuffer/3600460#3600460) to that question for a more complete example.